# Need Help Yielding a Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, yield-return, ienumerator

I'm running a coroutine where a GameObject's children's material.shaders are being manipulated. I just can't seem to figure out for the life of me how to make the coroutine wait until all of the materials are at the desired blend level, before going on to the next step. Everything's working just fine, I just need the coroutine not to continue past line 28 until all the materials are ChangedToWhite. Any thoughts?

```
public GameObject changeInto;

private bool coroutineStarted = false;
private Renderer[] renderersArray;
private List<Material> materialsList = new List<Material>();
private GameObject newForm;

void Start(){
    renderersArray = this.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
}
void Update(){
    if(!coroutineStarted){
        coroutineStarted = true;
        StartCoroutine(Change());
    }
}

private IEnumerator Change(){
    foreach(Renderer renderer in renderersArray){
        for(int i = 0; i < renderer.materials.Length; i++){
            if(renderer.materials[i].shader.name == "Toon/Basic Blender"){
                materialsList.Add(renderer.materials[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach(Material material in materialsList){
        StartCoroutine(ChangeToWhite(material));
    }
    animation.Play("Evolution");
    newForm = Instantiate(changeInto, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    yield return null;
}

private IEnumerator ChangeToWhite(Material mat){
    float counter = mat.GetFloat("_Blend");
    while(counter != 1f){
        float increase = mat.GetFloat("_Blend") + 0.01f;
        mat.SetFloat("_Blend", increase);
        counter += increase;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this part:

```
 foreach(Material material in materialsList){
        StartCoroutine(ChangeToWhite(material));
    }
```

has to contain the wait time of the change to white routine. In your case, it would be variable because you are not using Time.deltaTime which is HIGHLY encouraged by the way.

EDIT: here is the code you may want to use

```
foreach(Material material in materialsList){
        StartCoroutine(ChangeToWhite(material));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }

    private IEnumerator ChangeToWhite(Material mat){
    float counter = mat.GetFloat("_Blend");
    while(counter != 1f){ //the 1 here is the time to wait
        float increase = mat.GetFloat("_Blend") + Time.deltaTime;
        mat.SetFloat("_Blend", increase);
        counter += increase;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that in the portion of...`while(counter != 1f)`...to add some factor of Time.deltaTime?

Comment: I guess I should have said this in the OP, but I know WHERE the yield needs to be, I'm just not sure of what the criteria should be. For example...a while x is true, yield return null...etc...

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY...well...almost. The only problem now is that it's changing the materials one-by-one. I need it to change all the materials in the list simultaneously.

Comment: Meh...was as simple as taking the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);` and putting it after the foreach loop.